# Using a list of custom type for the underlying container of a priority queue

Tags: c++, list, priority-queue

My quest continues ! I started using a list for my priority queue

```
std::priority_queue<charElement,std::list<charElement>,compareCharElt> Q_freqDistribution;
```

where charElement does not (as of this erroneous compilation) overload the '-' operator

When I got this error :

```
std::_List_unchecked_iterator<_Mylist>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator *
```

I looked it up and from what I understood , it seemed that in order for me to be able to use a list (I assume for the iterator to be able to traverse elements) I needed to overload the '-' operator , so I did , here's the method header :

```
void operator-(charElement&);
```

At this point I just wanted a dummy operator to make sure what I understood was correct, sadly , I am wrong , I've been searching for a while about this now and I cant seem to be able to pin point the problem, can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying container for a `priority_queue` must be a sequence container with random access iterators (and `front()`, `push_back()` and `pop_back()` operations). `list` has bidirectional iterators, not random access iterators, so you can't use it here.

You can use `vector` (the default), `deque`, or any non-standard container that meets these requirements.

You shouldn't need to overload `operator-` for your type; the compiler is complaining that `operator-` is not overloaded for `list::iterator`. The only requirement on the type is that it can be compared with other values of that type; in your case, you're providing a custom comparator for that.